# iOS9 AVSpeechUtterance rate for AVSpeechSynthesizer issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios9, avspeechsynthesizer

The AVSpeechUtterance rate does not work the same for iOS 9 and prior versions of OS.
Which is the change I have to make so that the sentence is spoken at the same speed. Are there any other changes I need to make for iOS9?
It seems that multiplying the AVSpeechUtterance.rate by 6.0 works fine.
Thank you!

Comment: In what way doesn't it work the same for iOS9?

Comment: It speaks much slower, so I multiplied the rate by 6.0 for iOS9. But I don't like this solution.

Comment: I wouldn't use the same multiplier for any rate. The difference between the synthesizers might be 6x at a slow rate, but the two rates start to converge the closer you get to 1. See Ernie Thomason's answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I also see the change after compiling with the new XCode.  Below are my mappings from old to new speed.  I now have different speed assignments if device is <= iOS8 or >= iOS9.

```
           iOS 8   iOS 9
Very Slow  0       0.42
Slower     0.06    0.5
My Normal  0.15    0.53
Faster     0.23    0.56
```

Comment: this seems to be about right. have you also checked iOS7?

Comment: I just checked iOS 7.  It plays a little slower that iOS 8 for me.   I never realized this before.  For example, I think iOS 7 needs about .25 to get it to match .015 in iOS 8.  I provide a +/- 3 speed control so the user can deal with this small difference.

Comment: That is really unconsidered for Apple, my app is designed for people with disabilities and speed has to be exactly the same on all devices/iOS versions. Anybody knows exact conversion from version to version?

Answer (score 2):

I've bumped into this issue a few times, too. Given the frequency of changes to iOS lately, I set a default speech rate based on the iOS version the user is running in `AppDelegate.swift` like so:

```
// iOS speech synthesis is flakey between 8 and 9, so set default utterance rate based on iOS version
if NSProcessInfo().isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion(NSOperatingSystemVersion(majorVersion: 8, minorVersion: 0, patchVersion: 0)) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setFloat(0.15, forKey: "defaultSpeechRate")
    if NSProcessInfo().isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion(NSOperatingSystemVersion(majorVersion: 9, minorVersion: 0, patchVersion: 0)) {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setFloat(0.53, forKey: "defaultSpeechRate")
    }
} else {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setFloat(0.5, forKey: "defaultSpeechRate")
}
```

On my preferences scene, I added a slider to adjust the rate:

```
@IBOutlet var speechRateSlider: UISlider!
```

In `viewDidLoad`, I added the following:

```
    // Set speech rate
    speechRateSlider.value = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().floatForKey("defaultSpeechRate")
    speechRateSlider.maximumValue = 1.0
    speechRateSlider.minimumValue = 0.0
    speechRateSlider.continuous = true
    speechRateSlider.addTarget(self, action: "adjustSpeechRate:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

I also tied an action to the `UISlider`:

```
@IBAction func adjustSpeechRate(sender: AnyObject) {

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setFloat(speechRateSlider.value, forKey: "defaultSpeechRate")
    speechRateSlider.setValue(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().floatForKey("defaultSpeechRate"), animated: true)
    print(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().floatForKey("defaultSpeechRate"))
}
```

Given the unexpected behavior across devices and so many versions of iOS floating around, I opted to go this route rather than hard-code it into my app.