# AVSpeechSynthesizer utterance rate varying in iOS7 & iOS 9

Tags: objective-c, text-to-speech, ios9, xcode7, avspeechsynthesizer

Issue : In iOS 7.x and iOS 8.x this code is working fine, but in iOS 9.x rate of speech is getting slower as compare to rate of speech in iOS 7 & 8.

```
self.synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];

self.synthesizer.delegate = self;

AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hey %@, please choose places to explore or select excursions to see our custom crafted deals",[defaults objectForKey:@"USERNAME"]]];

utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-US"];

utterance.rate = 0.10;

[self.synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS9 AVSpeechUtterance rate for AVSpeechSynthesizer issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761786/ios9-avspeechutterance-rate-for-avspeechsynthesizer-issue)

Answer (score 3):

`[utterance setRate: 0.5f];` will do the job

Comment: [utterance setRate: 0.5f]; This will surely increase the rate of utterance.. but now on iOS 7 & iOS 8 it will become too fast

Comment: `if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] > 8.5) {
        [utterance setRate:0.5f];
    } else {
        [utterance setRate:0.1f];
    }` 

Comment: Yes this is something what we are doing, but why it is so ? Why the utterance rate is varying